# how to automatically cleanup failed PHP uploads in /tmp?

Tags: cron, php, tmp

How can I automatically cleanup failed uploads?
PHP is storing them in `/tmp` and all file names look like `phpAbCDeF` (basically php followed by 6 characters).

I know that I can use the command:

```
find /tmp -name php\*
```

BUT this also removes other temp files that begins with php (created by other processes) that I don't want to delete.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Is this a third-party application or something you wrote/can modify?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your files are named. Here are some suggestions:

1. delete all files whose name is `php` followed by exactly 6 characters:

   ```
   find /tmp -type f -name 'php??????' -delete
   ```
2. Delete all files whose name starts with `php` and which are **empty**:

   ```
   find /tmp -type f -name "php*"  -empty -delete
   ```
3. A better way would be to edit your server's `php-ini` file and set the variable `upload_tmp_dir`. That way, you can just delete everything in that directory. For example, if you set this in your `php.ini`:

   ```
   upload_tmp_dir=/tmp/phptmp
   ```

   You can then simply remove all files from the folder:

   ```
   rm  /tmp/phptmp/*
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an application that you wrote/can modify, I would recommend using `register_shutdown_function` at the time you create the temporary file. That way you can `unlink` even if your script is interrupted.